# How do I set default alignment for horizontal controls in Bootstrap-UI 3 for CakePHP 4?

Tags: forms, cakephp, bootstrap-4, cakephp-4.x

This is a particularly obscure question about the Boostrap-UI plugin for CakePHP but I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

I’m using Bootstrap-UI (https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui) version 3.0, so using Bootstrap 4.6.

I’m trying to create a form that has controls that are aligned horizontally with their labels using the example from the readme here -

[image]

This works fine except I can’t see how to define the default column distribution ie so that the classes for the label and the control container are something like `col-4` and `col-8` without any breakpoint defined.

If I try something like -

```
              'align' => [
                'left' => 4,
                'middle' => 8,
              ]
```

The classes created are `col-md-4` and `col-md-8` ie it seems to default to md as the breakpoint for the columns.

I know this is a bit obscure but does anyone have any idea how to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT that's currently not supported, meaning you can only generate the default `mb` breakpoint ones, or specify breakpoints yourself.

You can open an issue over at GitHub for a feature request. As a workaround you could extend the plugin'S form helper and overwrite `FormHelper::_gridClass()` to modify the generated classlist, something along the lines of this, which would remove the default breakpoint from the generated class string:

```php
namespace App\View\Helper;

class FormHelper extends \BootstrapUI\View\Helper\FormHelper
{
    protected function _gridClass(string $position, bool $offset = false): string
    {
        return str_replace('-md', '', parent::_gridClass($position, $offset));
    }
}
```

```php
public function initialize(): void
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->initializeUI();

    $this->helpers['Form'] = [
        'className' => \App\View\Helper\FormHelper::class
    ];
}
```

See also **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers**

Comment: Thanks for this @ndm. I was thinking I was going to have to do something like this but wasn't sure how to go about it. My version of `_gridclass` does things a bit differently to yours but the approach and structure are the same.